# Power-shell Output and optimization

Tags: powershell, foreach, richtextbox

I am new to power-shell and attempting to write a VMreset script. I have everything working but have a few questions about some things.

Below is the function that runs pretty all the commands

I notice that sometimes it takes forever the for the code to run, it didn't before I added the End-Process, Remove-Item and Copy-Item Commands

Also it now seems as through the Write-Output is being displayed after all the commands execute.

Is there a better way for me to be doing this?

```
function OS-Windows7 {
    Foreach ($Computer in $global:ComputerList) {

    Write-Output "Starting VMReset on $Computer"
    Write-Output "Looking for active VMWare Processes to kill on $Computer"
    End-Process 'vmware-vmx'
    End-Process 'vmware'
    End-Process 'vmware-tray'
    Write-Output "Removing altered virtual machines on $Computer"
    Remove-Item \\$Computer\C$\"My Virtual Machines\*" -Force -Recurse
    Write-Output "Replacing altered virtual machines on $Computer"
    Copy-Item "\\$Computer\C$\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\VM\Child\*" "\\$Computer\C$\My Virtual Machines\" -recurse -force
    Write-Output "VMReset Finished on $Computer"
    }
}
```

Comment: End-Process is not a standard PowerShell cmdlet. Apparently this is a function you wrote?  Is it possible that function (not shown here) is doing something to cause the delay?  Does it do something more than the built-in Stop-Process cmdlet?

Comment: function End-Process {
        param([string[]]$ProcessName)
        Stop-Process -Process $ProcessName
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using WS-Management to handle the copies and remove will be much faster since all tasks will be run on the remote. Actions on big files like the VM ones are very costly when done over a remote share instead of locally.

WS-Management

- Setup: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx
- Use: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx